# Salesforce apex:output link image not downloading

Tags: apex, visualforce, images, commandlink

I am trying to get images in table and when we click on that image,it should get download.I am using apex:outputLink but image is not downloading.

```
<apex:column >
   <apex:facet name="header">File</apex:facet>
   <!-- apex:outputlink styleClass="{!IF(AttachVar.ViewingStatus == 'Not Viewed' && (runningUser.Profile.Name == 'Profile1' || runningUser.Profile.Name == 'Profile2'),'actionLink disableLink','actionLink')}"target="_BLANK" value="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!AttachVar.attachmentID}" >{!AttachVar.attachmentName}
        <apex:actionSupport  event="onclick" action="{!updateHistory1}" >
            <apex:param value="{!AttachVar.attachmentID}" name="updateHistory1" assignTo="{!SelectedId1}"/>
        </apex:actionSupport>
    </apex:outputlink -->
</apex:column>
```

I used commandLink as well but it is also not opening the image.

Comment: N.B. `runningUser.Profile.Name` can be replaced with `$Profile.Name`. Does the URL work (to download the image) when entered in the browser directly?

Comment: URL is working.

Comment: so you want the outputLink to display as an image?  Don't you want `<apex:outputLink ...><apex:image ...></apex:outputLink>`

Comment: I want image to get download after clicking on the link.