# Salesforce apex:commandLink image not downloading

Tags: visualforce

I want image to get download or disply after clicking on link.

Visualforce page :-

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!DORESAttachmentsWrapperList}" var="AttachVar" border="3px" width="98.5%">    
<apex:column >    
<apex:facet name="header">File</apex:facet>    
<apex:commandLink action="{!DORESupdateHistory1}" styleClass="{!IF(AttachVar.DoresViewingStatus == 'Not Viewed' && (runningUser.Profile.Name == 'Profile1' || runningUser.Profile.Name =='Profile2'),'actionLink disableLink','actionLink')}"    
value="{!AttachVar.attachmentName}" >  
<apex:param value="{!AttachVar.attachmentID}" name="DORESupdateHistory1" assignTo="{!DORESSelectedId1}"/>  
</apex:commandLink >  
</apex:column>
```

Controller -
DORESupdateHistory1 will update the timing and name of the person in a table who clicks on the new attached image.

```
 public String DORESSelectedId1{get;set;}  

     public PageReference DORESupdateHistory1(){  
         system.debug('--DORESSelectedId1---' + DORESSelectedId1);  
         List<Profile> Profile= [Select Name from Profile where Id =:UserInfo.getProfileId() LIMIT 1];    
         list<attachment> relatedPaadAttachment = [select ID,parentID,name from attachment where ID=:DORESSelectedId1 limit 1];  
         system.debug('--DORESSelectedId1---' + DORESSelectedId1);    
         List<PAAD_Application_Attachment__c> ClickedAttachList1 = [Select id,Name,Type__c,CreatedDate,Dores_Viewer_Name__c,Dores_Viewed_Time__c,Dores_Viewing_Status__c from PAAD_Application_Attachment__c where id = :relatedPaadAttachment[0].parentID]; //To get the clicked attachment Id  
 if(ClickedAttachList1[0].Dores_Viewing_Status__c == 'Not Viewed' && Profile[0].Name == 'Profile1' || Profile[0].Name == 'Profile2'){  
 ClickedAttachList1[0].Dores_Viewing_Status__c = 'Viewed';  
 ClickedAttachList1[0].Dores_Viewed_Time__c = system.now();  
 ClickedAttachList1[0].Dores_Viewer_Name__c = UserInfo.getName();  
 update ClickedAttachList1;  
 List<PAAD_Application_Attachment__c> viewedattach1= [SELECT Id,Dores_Viewing_Status__c FROM PAAD_Application_Attachment__c where Dores_Viewing_Status__c != 'Viewed' and PAAD_Applicant__c=:app.ID];  
List<PAAD_Application_Attachment__c> attach1 = [SELECT Id FROM PAAD_Application_Attachment__c where PAAD_Applicant__c=:app.ID];  
  if(viewedattach1.size() == attach1.size()){  
 List<PAAD_Applicant__c> attachcheck1= [SELECT Id,New_Dores_Attachment_Checker__c FROM PAAD_Applicant__c where ID=:app.ID];  
                if(attachcheck1[0].New_Dores_Attachment_Checker__c == 'Y') {  
                    attachcheck1[0].New_Dores_Attachment_Checker__c = '';  
                    update attachcheck1;  
                }     
            }  
    List<AttachmentWrapper>  dummyWrapperList = new List<AttachmentWrapper>();   
            for(AttachmentWrapper wrap : DORESAttachmentsWrapperList){  
                if(DORESSelectedId1 !=  wrap.attachmentID){  
                    dummyWrapperList.add(wrap);  
                }else{  
                    dummyWrapperList.add(new AttachmentWrapper(ClickedAttachList1[0].Type__c,ClickedAttachList1[0].Member__c, ClickedAttachList1[0].Description_Final__c, relatedPaadAttachment[0].ID,relatedPaadAttachment[0].name, ClickedAttachList1[0].CreatedDate,'Attached', ClickedAttachList1[0].Dores_Viewed_Time__c, ClickedAttachList1[0].Dores_Viewer_Name__c, ClickedAttachList1[0].Dores_Viewing_Status__c));    
                }  
            }  
            DORESAttachmentsWrapperList.clear();  
            DORESAttachmentsWrapperList.addAll(dummyWrapperList);  
         }    
         return null;  
     }
```

Comment: pleasxe use [edit] to format/indent the code

Comment: Please **edit** your [existing questions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/279450/salesforce-apexoutput-link-image-not-downloading) to add information, rather than reposting.